# Raw byte[] from Hanler Intptr Mplayer.exe netcat stream

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, arrays, netcat, intptr

Problem in getting the raw data from wid handler of a picturebox.

This code display in picturebox1 the streamed video using netcat and mplayer for low latency use.

How can I get images frame by frame to do some processing on the data?
I need to get the data as byte of array.
If there is a solution in WPF, it's even better.

```
int IDP = (int)pictureBox1.Handle;
pictureBox1.LoadProgressChanged += pictureBox1_LoadProgressChanged;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c nc64.exe -L -p 5003 | mplayer.exe -framedrop -wid " + IDP + " -vo directx -fps 120 -cache 1024 -";
p.Start();
```

Comment: You are piping the results directly (using '|') from the nc64.exe to mplayer.exe.  Instead you need to send the output of nc64.exe to standard output so you can get results inside you c# application.

Comment: Yes but my problem is that the raw data is compressed, I need to see the data decoded that is why I had to pass by mplayer.exe.
Do you think there is other solution or workaround?

Comment: 'See Data' and 'Process Frame by Frame' aren't necessarily the same. I'm not sure what you mean by compressed.  Is each Frame compressed or is the stream capturing only deltas between each frame.   Maybe use -vo option.  See webpage : http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/fbdev.html.  Also see : https://dzone.com/articles/how-extract-video-still-frames

Comment: The stream is MJPEG, what I need is see frame by frame in Byte array format or Bitmap so I will be able to process them.